# Simulación de accesos directos en Formularios MDI Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, accesibilidad

Quería simular, en un formulario MDI, accesos directos a opciones de menú a través de botones que pertenecen al MDI.

[[image: Pantalla de muestra1]

El problema es que cuando se abren las ventanas los botones, o cualquier otro objeto, quedan  por encima de ellas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así llamo al formulario

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form1 f = new Form1();
       f.MdiParent = this;
       f.Show();
    }
```

Probé con varios controles diferentes que con todos pasa lo mismo.

Lo único que se me ocurrió es hacer desaparecer los botones cuando hay algún formulario abierto. Pero ya los accesos directos no tendrían tanto sentido.

¿Alguien intentó hacer algo así?
¿Hay alguna alternativa?

Desde ya les agradezco

Saludos

Comment: Como estas llamando al Form1 ? muestra el código

Comment: Perdón. Me comí poner el código

    Así llamo al formulario 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Form1 f = new Form1();
           f.MdiParent = this;
           f.Show();
        }

Comment: Debes ocultar los botones (Hide) al abrir cualquier Form y cuando no haya ningun Form abierto mostrarlos.  Entonces por cada click del boton llamas a metodo que tu crees OcultarBotonesMenu  y  MostrarBotonesMenu para cuando cierres un Form,

Comment: Esa es la opción que se me había ocurrido. Pero me da la sensación que no cumple por completo con el objetivo.